# Count the height of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, ipython, binary-tree

I want to caculate the height of a binary tree wihout using the algorithme that takes the maximum of the depths of each leaf. 
This is the structure that I have on eache node 
`[content, left_son, right_son, father_node]` 
a list of arrays of size 4 that represents every node. the left_son, right_son, and father are respectively the indexes of the the left son node, the right son node and the father node in the list

Comment: It seems like you're out of luck... You'll have to take the maximum of the height of each of your children into account by definition of the height.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible, but you have to rework your data structure a bit:
You can store a binary Tree in an array like this:

- Store the value of the root node at index 0.
- Store the left child of
  a node at index 2*i+1, where i is the index of the current node;
  right child goes at index 2*i+2.

If you do it like this

- a node's parent is saved at index (i-1)/2.
- your array needs the length 2^(h+1)-1, where h is the height of the tree.

So all you have to do ist keep track of the last "used" index in your array and use the above formula to calculate the height.

```
2^(h+1)-1 = l => h = ceil(ld(l+1))-1
```

whith l being the length of your array you effictively use and ld the logarithm with base 2.

Comment: How do I manage the fact that a node might not have a right/left child and it takes the None value in this case ?

Comment: @Akram Bendoukha: In general a not existing node has to be marked by a special value i.e. `null` or -1. If you expect having "empty nodes" at the end of your array, I recommend keeping track of the last filled entry by storing it's index in an extra variable. This way you can use the formula directly.